# Select multiple rows from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables in mysql database. Like Groups, GroupsMembers, Messages.

**Groups**

```
| group_id |  group_name  | group_image
-------------------------------------------
| group_1    | First Group  | group1.jpg
| group_2    | 2nd Group    | group2.jpg
| group_3    | 3rd Group    | group3.jpg
| group_4    | 4th Group    | group4.jpg
| group_5    | 5th Group    | group5.jpg
| group_6    | 6th Group    | group6.jpg
```

**Messages**

```
| sender_id |  group_id  | message | time 
-----------------------------------------
| 001    | group_1    | first message | 2017-07-13 15:05:07
| 002    | group_2    | fifth message | 2017-07-13 15:04:07
| 002    | group_2    | third Message | 2017-07-13 15:03:07
```

**GroupsMembers**

```
| user_id |  group_id 
-----------------------------------------
| 001    | group_1 
| 001    | group_2 
| 002    | group_2 
| 002    | group_1 
| 002    | group_4 
| 002    | group_6
```

I am trying with this query

```
SELECT mmbr.group_id, grp.group_name, grp.group_image, msg.time, msg.message FROM `GroupsMembers` AS mmbr JOIN `Messages` AS msg ON msg.group_id =mmbr.group_id AND msg.time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM `Messages` WHERE group_id = mmbr.group_id) JOIN `Groups` AS grp ON grp.group_id = mmbr.group_id WHERE mmbr.user_id = '002'
```

It gives me following result:-

```
| group_id |  group_name    | group_image | time                | message |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| group_1    | First Group  | group1.jpg  | 2017-07-13 15:05:07 | first message
| group_2    | 2nd Group    | group2.jpg  | 2017-07-13 15:04:07 | fifth message
```

*But* *I* *need* *all* *groups* *of* *userid* *'002'* *with* *message* *or* *without*. **Something** **like** **this**:-
**need** **last** **sent** **message** **if** **any**

```
| group_id   |  group_name  | group_image | time                | message |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| group_1    | First Group  | group1.jpg  | 2017-07-13 15:05:07 | first message
| group_2    | 2nd Group    | group2.jpg  | 2017-07-13 15:04:07 | fifth message
| group_4    | 4th Group    | group4.jpg  |  null               |  null
| group_6    | 6th Group    | group6.jpg  |  null               |  null
```

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try with LEFT JOIN and then i will update here.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. LEFT JOIN works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consider using LEFT Join

```
SELECT mmbr.group_id, grp.group_name, grp.group_image, msg.time, msg.message FROM `GroupsMembers` AS mmbr 
JOIN `Groups` AS grp ON grp.group_id = mmbr.group_id 
LEFT JOIN `Messages` AS msg ON msg.group_id =mmbr.group_id AND msg.time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM `Messages` WHERE group_id = mmbr.group_id) 
WHERE mmbr.user_id = '002'
```

Read this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: It gives mysql error "Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near WHERE)"

Comment: Try now, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Thanks @Joey Pinto. I just put WHERE clause in the end and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT mmbr.group_id,
       grp.group_name,
       grp.group_image,
       msg.time,
       msg.message
FROM   `GroupsMembers` AS mmbr
JOIN   `Groups` AS grp
  ON   grp.group_id = mmbr.group_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Messages` AS msg
             ON msg.group_id = mmbr.group_id
            AND msg.time = (SELECT MAX(time)
                            FROM `Messages`
                            WHERE group_id = mmbr.group_id)
WHERE  mmbr.user_id = '002';
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply LEFT JOIN.

Try this

SELECT mmbr.group_id, grp.group_name, grp.group_image, msg.time, msg.message FROM `GroupsMembers AS mmbr LEFT JOIN`Messages`AS msg ON msg.group_id =mmbr.group_id AND msg.time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM`Messages`WHERE group_id = mmbr.group_id) LEFT JOIN`Groups` AS grp ON grp.group_id = mmbr.group_id WHERE mmbr.user_id = '002'